# appending data without using global vars

Tags: kdb

Often I have to union join to append some data, using a global var result.

```
res();
{[someVar]
    res,:: select x from y where (constraints related to someVar)
} each list of someVars
```

This is not exactly very functional style. Is there a different way to achieve this w/o globals?

Answer (score 4):

A couple of points:

1. You don't need the double colon to assign globally when you're doing an append-in-place (aka `a,:b` as opposed to `a::a,b`). A single will work in this case since append-in-place works in the global context.
2. You're discounting the fact that append-in-place is very memory-efficient even if it is not "functional" and uses global context. For example:

   ```
   q)\ts t:([]col1:10000000?100j)
   110 134218192

   q)\ts a:{x,select from y}/[t;2 cut ([]col1:til 6)]
   74 268436720

   q)\ts {t,:x} each 2 cut ([]col1:til 6)
   0 1424
   q)a~t
   1b
   ```

The method of iterating using over (/) and avoiding globals creates a copy of the table thus doubling the memory usage. The append-in-place uses very little memory for the same result.

So ultimately there are some situations where having the global is a worthy trade-off, depends on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

```
res:(),/{[someVar]
    select x from y where (constraints related to someVar)
} each someVars
```

will take the list of returned tables and join them back onto res with the over adverb (/)

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#over

Comment: key word `raze` is alternative to (),/ .e.g
`raze {select from ([]1 2;3 4)} each til 3`